# rails update method not calling class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a class method that I need to call on a controller update method called auto_assign!

It essentially finds the artist with the lowest amount of requests and assigns that artist id to the object.

It works perfectly on the create method, but it does not get called on the update method, and I am not sure why.

Controller

```
  def update
    @virtual_request = VirtualRequest.find(params[:id])
    @virtual_request.auto_assign! # this never gets called

    if @virtual_request.update_attributes(virtual_params)
      flash[:success] = "Virtual request updated"
      redirect_to virtual_request_path(@virtual_request)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
    @virtual_request = VirtualRequest.new(virtual_params)
    @virtual_request.auto_assign! # works fine here!

    if @virtual_request.save
      flash[:success] = "Virtual has been created and assigned to # {@virtual_request.artist.name}"
      redirect_to virtual_requests_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Class VirtualRequest

```
def auto_assign!
  if self.artist_id == 0
    artists = Artist.in_queue?.collect {|p| [ p.id, p.virtual_requests.count ] } 
    self.artist_id = artists.sort { |a,b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.first[0]
  end
end
```

HTML sending parameters

```
<select id="virtual_request_artist_id" name="virtual_request[artist_id]">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">auto-assign</option>
    <option value="2">Artist 1</option>
    <option value="5">Artist 2</option>
</select>
```

it is supposed to auto-assign when the value in the params is 0

**UPDATE: solved**

Controller

```
def update
  @virtual_request = VirtualRequest.find(params[:id])

  if @virtual_request.update_attributes(virtual_params)
    @virtual_request.auto_assign!
    flash[:success] = "Virtual request updated"
    redirect_to virtual_request_path(@virtual_request)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Class

```
def auto_assign!
  if self.artist_id == 0
    artists = Artist.in_queue?.collect {|p| [ p.id, p.virtual_requests.count ] } 
    self.artist_id = artists.sort { |a,b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.first[0]
    self.save
  end
end
```

Comment: If 'VirtualRequest.find(params[:id])' doesn't fail, your auto_assign method has to be called! Can you post the method please?

Comment: What's actually happening though? Are you getting the flash message from the update action?

Comment: yeah I am getting the flash method, it ends up applying an artist_id of 0 to the instance, instead of assigning one like it should

Comment: and what happens if you remove this line: `@virtual_request.auto_assign!` form the update action? does everything else work as expected?

Comment: yes, everything works fine, except applying the correct artist_id, both with and without @virtual_request.auto_assign!

Comment: but how are you sending the `:id` from your form? The VirtualRequest ID that is

Comment: parameters are being sent like this -

Parameters: {"virtual_request"=>{ ...., "artist_id"=>"0", "id"=>"52"} (shortened for readability)

everything is being updated succesfully, and when I try to run the method in console, it works great. but for some reason inside the update method it does not work)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40282/discussion-between-tommyd456-and-matt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong:

First you need to call the `@virtual_request.auto_assign!` within the conditional because artist_id would not have been set otherwise.

Secondly don't forget to `save` the updated instance when you make the changes in the auto_assign method so:

```
def update
  @virtual_request = VirtualRequest.find(params[:id])

  if @virtual_request.update(virtual_params)
    @virtual_request.auto_assign!
    @virtual_request.save
    flash[:success] = "Virtual request updated"
    redirect_to virtual_request_path(@virtual_request)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

something on these lines but I'm sure others will suggest a more efficient solution

alternatively for your method (you won't need the `save` in your Controller with this approach).

```
def auto_assign!
  if self.artist_id == 0
    artists = Artist.in_queue?.collect {|p| [ p.id, p.virtual_requests.count ] } 
    artist_id = artists.sort { |a,b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.first[0]
    self.update_attribute(:artist_id,artist_id)
  end
end
```

a few things to play with anyway!

Comment: hey fyi, I just tried that with update, and it did not work, i had to put the .save in the class method regardless. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: sorry missed that after telling you ha ha - this is not the most efficient way to do this - this is a bit of a rush job admittedly but I've run out of time - but it has solved your problem though